# where to put infinite loop in android app to handle tweens

Tags: android, loops, tween

I would like to make use of the universal tween engine in my pure android app, and understand that I will need to put a loop somewhere which will update the tweenmanager every frame. I have used this before in game projects where i have access to the game loop provided but in the case of a pure android application, where would I create this loop and what is the best way to handle this as my app is opened/closed/paused/resumed etc?

Am I best creating a new thread in the onResume method for each activity and starting the loop there and ending the loop in the onPause method? or is it better to create a class that acts as a sort of "Activity manager" and is always available? if so how would I do this?

Comment: So you just want a callback to be executed at every frame?  What API level are you targeting?

Comment: its ok. i have found some useful documentation at https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wikis/AndroidUI.wiki

Comment: though it would still be very useful to know where to create a class which i can store values in which would be available throughout the lifetime of my application regardless of activity. though i will ask this in another question

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful documentation on this at https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wikis/AndroidUI.wiki and It seems the 'correct' way to achieve this is to create a new loop for each activity in onResume() and end the loop in onPause()

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available starting in API level 16 called [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html).  This is the thing that keeps the main thread pumping events at 60 frames per second.  You can register a callback to be executed with the next frame, then within that callback, register to run it again at the next frame.  This is the most reliable way to get called at every frame with near-perfect timing (as long as the main thread is not being blocked in a way that would case frame loss).

Your callbacks will all be called on the main thread, so be careful yourself about blocking the main thread. So keep your work super fast.